# Write once read many memory

Tags: memory

i'm looking for a WORM memory with a fast and not serialized access (like CD or DVD). Do you know if exists this kind of memory such as USB memory or Compact Flash? Googeling i did not find anything, there were some sandisk news about a SD Worm card but nothing in official web site.
I need this for a cash register software log.

Thank you.

Comment: I know that question is pretty old, but did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem with law specification.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I found this http://www.scm-pc-card.de/index.php?lang=en&page=product&function=show_product&product_id=676 but seems that Sandisk discontinued the production of SD Worm memories. I decided to use a evening batch to write a CD-R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question...

4 year after I found a memory manufacturer that can customize his microSD firmware to become a WORM memory and I'm going to sell these cards.

I did not find any other solution.

Comment: Did you start selling this? :)

Comment: Are you interested?

Comment: Yes! My father is

Answer (score 0):

First, there might be a reason such things often use paper tape - it's fairly easy to audit, both to convince yourself that it is logging, and to go back over the log without special tools.  Though of course it doesn't store nicely or even age particularly well.

Some types of flash ICs may have non-reversable erase-locking at a sector level. Historically there have been one-time-programmable technologies, such proms or UV eproms in un-windowed pacakges, but mostly in relatively small (or perhaps I should say tiny) capacities compared to modern consumer flash. These might get increasingly difficult to source.

If you negotiate for access to the full SD card spec you will find out about all sorts of additional mechanisms supported by some cards - there might or might not be something there of use to you.

On the pure software front, with off-the-shelf USB-key, SD-card, or even magnetic disk media, you could try to use digital signatures to authenticate the information which is written.  You couldn't block erasure, but you could use sequence numbers to indicate something was lost.  If the sourcing program is cracked for the key, that could be used to forge entries, but then if the running copy of the sourcing program can be cracked and patched, it might be writing false entries anyway.

Comment: Thanks Chris, the italian law about cash software says that digital memory must be immutable and I think progressives and digital signature is not compatible with this specification (also if I agree with you).
I really need something like hard drive (CF, SD, USB Drive) that elettronically can not be erased... The only other choice seems to be the glorious CD-R... but it has a not very nice write system becausa I just have to write some KBytes daily...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SanDisk Memory Vault, not sure if it will meet your needs but it seems to be a 'WORM' like flash drive product.

Comment: I saw this device, but in the user manual I read that you can erase some times the storage... this is not a WORM if you can erase :-(

Comment: Seems that the memory become WORM only after it is full.